# PowerApps ContactGetItemsV2 and ForAll

Tags: office365, powerapps

I have researched this quite a bit and am struggling to figure out the solution. I'd sure appreciate some guidance.

I have a powerapp that uses ContactGetTables to populate a combo box with a list of all contact folders in Outlook365. So, if a user has 3 Contact folders, it will populate with CB with the displayName of each.

The user is allowed to select one or more of those displaynames and hit a button that will email a message to all recipients in the selected contact folders. The flow works but, I'd like to insert a step that notifies the user after they press the button, "Hey, you're about to email X,XXX people. You're cool with that, right?"

My challenge is collecting the number of contacts in each group. I am relatively confident that it has something to do with a formula like this:

ForAll(cb_SendToFolders.SelectedItems As _item, Count(OfficeOutlook365.ContactGetItemsV2(_item)))

Something along those lines, I need to get the count and add it to the total. For the life of me, I cant get this to work. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sum(
  ForAll(cb_SendToFolders.SelectedItems As _item, 
    Count( OfficeOutlook365.ContactGetItemsV2(_item) )
  ),
  Value
)
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?